# Select updated row immediately after updating the row using Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, node.js

My goal is to `select` the updated row immediately using `promise.all()`. I am using `promise.all()` because I think that how I can bypass the node.js asynchronous The row is updated succesfully but the `select` statement is not returning anything. I am working with mysql database. I will appreciate any assistance. Thanks.

```
const query = promisify(db.query.bind(db));
Promise.all( [query("UPDATE order_detail SET tracking_number = '2323211' where order_detail_id = 81")])
.then(() => query('select * from order_detail where order_detail_id = ?', [81]))
.then(data => {
   console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: Why use `Promise.all` if there's only one promise you're passing it?

Comment: @eol I thought that will be a way for me to bypass the asynchronous of node.js. I am also open suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: @NaheemOlaniyan wdym with bypassing? You can make all async code work out sync as well (however that will be much slower)

Comment: @Zer0 My thought is that I would not be able to fetch the data immediately after inserting  in node.js. Please do you have any better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do your operations inside `then`

```
const query = promisify(db.query.bind(db));
Promise.all([query("UPDATE order_detail SET tracking_number = '2323211' where order_detail_id = 81")])
  .then(() => {
    query('select * from order_detail where order_detail_id = ?', [81]).then((data) => console.log(data))
  })
```

Comment: @NaheemOlaniyan this should work now.if you can check?

Comment: I am trying to do some thing inside the  `.then` after  `console.log(data)` but am getting an error. Please do you have any suggestion to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

`promiseAll()` with `.then` and `async await`

using `.then`:

```js
const query = promisify(db.query.bind(db));
Promise.all([query("UPDATE order_detail SET tracking_number = '2323211' where order_detail_id = 81")])
    .then(() => {
        query('select * from order_detail where order_detail_id = ?', [81])
          .then((data) => console.log(data));
    });
```

Using `async` and `await`:

```js
const run = async () => {
    const query = promisify(db.query.bind(db));
    const resultArr = await Promise.all([query("UPDATE order_detail SET tracking_number = '2323211' where order_detail_id = 81")]);
    const result = await query('select * from order_detail where order_detail_id = ?', [81]);
}
run();
```